# How to navigate to the HTML element in the same page using javascript...

Tags: javascript, html

I want to navigate to an HTML element having a particular 'id' in the same page using javascript on click of a button.

for example:

```
<body>
   <div id="navigateHere" >
   </div>

   <button onclicK="navigate();" />
```

In the above code what should be there in the javascript function navigate() , so that on a click of a button , it will navigate to the 'div' element with  an id 'navigateHere'.....

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 window.location = "#navigateHere";
```

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a button, you can use a simple link:

```
<div><a href="#navigateHere">Link text</a></div>
```

If you need to use JavaScript and a button, something like the following should work:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="someid">Link text</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("someid").onclick = function () {
    window.location.hash = "#navigateHere";
};
```

Comment: I've posted the JavaScript as well.

Comment: For me it works if I use "href"  window.location.href= "#navigateHere";

Answer (score 3):

> It will navigate to the `div` element...

This may be what you want.

```
window.location.hash = 'navigateHere';
```

There is no need to use JavaScript though. Just link to `#navigateHere`.

Comment: `window.location.hash = '#navigateHere';` (with the hash) should work; your code currently does not.

Comment: @mc10: Works fine for me in Firefox without the hash.

Comment: According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), `location.hash` is "the part of the URL that follows the # symbol, **including the # symbol**".

Comment: @mc10: That's when it is returned. Setting it is different.