# Jump to a <Section> when a Textfield gets clicked

Tags: javascript, html

so i dont know how to approach it. I got my HTML

```
<input type="text">
```

Is it possible to jump to a

```
<section>
```

when i click on the textfield so the textfield jumps to the top of the screen so its easier to see?
thanks for reading

Comment: Put a id to section, then navigate to id using js. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177918/how-to-navigate-to-the-html-element-in-the-same-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little example for you in [codepen](https://codepen.io/HenrikDK/pen/BaoXjQx)

```js
//Replace something with your textfields id.
const inputTag = document.getElementById('something');
inputTag.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  //The sections id on your page
  window.location = "#about-section";
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for writing the whole example!

Comment: Ah interesting. It works perfectly on PC but there is a bug (?) when im on my smartphone. It jumps down like wanted but then I cant write in the textfield anymore